# How to manage serialisation/deserialization of Web api controller in asp .Net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I want to send to my Web Api controller some serialized entity.

For example like this:

```
var rectification = {};
rectification.id = "some string";
rectification.idType = "string";
rectification.objectId = "56d560564ee6bc45a0d7b711"
rectification.type="ObjectId"

$.ajax({
        url: '/controller/method',
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(rectification),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#Results").show();
            $("#ResultMessage").html(data.Message);
        }
    });
```

Then in my web api controller I want to deserialize it according to some rules which should be common to all controllers and I want to describe those rules in some C# code class. I realize that MediaTypeFormatters implementation should be used for this purpose, but can't find good advice how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MethodName(ViewModel model)
{
// Your Code here       
}

public class ViewModel 
{   
//All your property which you passing from view to controller via AJAX  
public string id { get; set; }
public string idType { get; set; }
public string objectId { get; set; }
public string type{ get; set; }
}
```

Your Method will parse data and set by key. but make sure both side (client side and Server side) key name must be same.

Comment: I want to change standard mapping. That's why I can't use your advice

Comment: Actually I need to modify existing standard mapping

Comment: Try this it will work for you. because it's standard and safe way to pass data via ajax to method in controller.

Comment: I use your proposition in other parts. Now I need extend it